# Malloc()ing in external function results in memory leak

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc

I know this is a common problem, however in my case the answer is not that straightforward (or at least I think so).

What I want is to allocate memory for 10 integers (as seen in the scheme below).

**Scheme:**

```
                               _____HEAP_____
                              |              |
**numbers ----->  *number  ---|-->  int      |
                  *number  ---|-->  int      |
                  *number  ---|-->  int      |
                   ..         |              |
                  *number  ---|-->  int      |
                              |______________|
```

**Code:**

```
int** numbers;

void malloc_number(int* number){
    number = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main(){

    numbers = malloc(10*sizeof(int*));
    int n;
    for (n=0; n < 10; n++){
        //numbers[n] = malloc(sizeof(int)); // THIS WORKS
        malloc_number(numbers[n]);          // THIS DOESN'T
        free(numbers[n]);
    }
    free(numbers);
}
```

I don't seem to understand why this isn't working. In my mind `numbers[n]` that I pass to `malloc_number` is a pointer to some unallocated number. Then I use `number = malloc(sizeof(int));` (number = numbers[n]) to allocate memory to that pointer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try '*number = malloc(sizeof(int))'

Comment: C is pass-by-**value**...

Answer (score 3):

```
   void malloc_number(int* number){
    number = malloc(sizeof(int));
   }
```

This function leaks memory. Remember C is pass-by-value and `number` argument is an object with automatic storage duration that got destroyed when `malloc_number` returns. If you want to modify a pointer through a function you have to pass a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: That's what I don't get. What does it matter if `number` is destroyed? It just holds the address to somewhere, and when it has been destroyed that address has already been alocated.. hurts my brain.

Comment: @Pithikos with `number = malloc(sizeof(int));` you are not modifying the pointer object you passed as as argument to `malloc_number` as C is pass-by-value. So what you end up having is something similar to `(void) malloc(sizeof(int));` which means some memory is allocated but you have no mean to free it as you lost the value of its location: that's what we call a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

```
void malloc_number(int* number){
    number = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

This code is wrong. You're setting the value of the var "number" which is an argument and is lost after the function call.
The right code would be:

```
void malloc_number(int** number){
    *number = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
...
malloc_number(&numbers[n]);
```

Please also note that the convention for loop increments to be "i" or "j", n being kind of reserved for the maximum value or limit.